CSRF Token invalid or missing even though it's being sent
I am working on Genesys Engage voice controls via Rest Api (Genesys Web Services). I am able to authenticate my agent and then I retrieve the X-CSRF-TOKEN and JSESSIONID from the response headers.
I use those values in my new request headers to trigger a "Dial" command for example. However, I still get the 403 response with status message "Csrf token invalid or missing".
Currently I'm still in the discovery phase of this task. This is a command line application in C# (.NET 4.6.2) for test automation.
Like I said, before calling the Dial method, I call the Authenticate method (GET), where I am successfully able to retrieve data like Device Id, X-CSRF-TOKEN, Cookie (JSESSIONID). My Authorization is just basic authorization. So in the example below, my "auth" variable would look something like: "Basic 08j3nEwXtmi2wepifmnPo0180=".
I've already read documentation like https://docs.genesys.com/Documentation/HTCC/8.5.2/API/CSRFProtection and https://docs.genesys.com/Documentation/HTCC/8.5.2/API/CallsDial for example and it seems that I'm including everything that is needed.
These are my current "Dial" and "SendRequest" functions:
        public string Dial(string number)
        {
            var message = new HttpRequestMessage(HttpMethod.Post, $"{baseUrl}/api/v2/me/devices/{this.Id}/calls");
            message.Headers.Add("Accept", "*/*");
            message.Headers.Add("X-CSRF-TOKEN", X_CSRF_TOKEN);
            message.Headers.Add("Authorization", auth);
            message.Headers.Add("Cookie", J_SESSION_ID);

            var body = new
            {
                operationName = "Dial",
                destination = new
                {
                    phoneNumber = number
                }
            };
            var jsonContent = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(body);
            message.Content = new StringContent(jsonContent, System.Text.Encoding.UTF8, "application/json");

            var result = sendRequest(message);
            JObject jResult = string.IsNullOrEmpty(result) ? new JObject() : JObject.Parse(result);
            return DateTime.Now.ToString();
        }

        private string sendRequest(HttpRequestMessage message)
        {
            var _httpClient = new HttpClient();
            HttpResponseMessage response = new HttpResponseMessage();
            Task<HttpResponseMessage> task = null;
            task = Task.Run(() =>
            {
                var re = _httpClient.SendAsync(message);
                return re;
            });
            task.Wait();
            response = task.Result;
            task.Dispose();

            Task<string> contentTask = Task.Run(async () => await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync());
            contentTask.Wait();
            var result = contentTask.Result;
            if (!response.IsSuccessStatusCode)
            {
                Utils.log.Info("There is an error in the response: " + result);
                return "";
            }
            else return result;
        }

When I call the Dial method, I get a result "Csrf token invalid or missing".
By the way, these steps work via Postman for example. (Authenticate, get the token and session ID, send the POST request to server with the correct headers and body => the call is started)

By the way, I forgot to mention that I've tried different variations of the X-CSRF-TOKEN key, such as "X-Csrf-Token, X-CSRFToken, x-csrf-token" and others... it doesn't make a difference
